# Cannot install/upgrade packags in linux mint, both terminal and package manager

Tags: linux-mint, terminal, package-management, vlc

As mentioned, cannot install packages. I tried to install VLC in package manager and there's an error message

```
installArchives() failed: Selecting previously unselected package libaribb24-0:amd64.
(Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5%%
(Reading database ... 10%%
(Reading database ... 15%%
(Reading database ... 20%%
(Reading database ... 25%%
(Reading database ... 30%%
(Reading database ... 35%%
(Reading database ... 40%%
(Reading database ... 45%%
(Reading database ... 50%%
(Reading database ... 55%%
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
files list file for package 'libstdc++-6-dev:amd64' contains empty filename
```

And basically any other packages also does this.
And I tried to do this:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/available 
sudo touch /var/lib/dpkg/available
sudo sh -c 'for i in /var/lib/apt/lists/*_Packages; do dpkg --merge-avail "$i"; done'
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

And no progress had been made, still the same error.
In terminal after typing

```
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

I get this:

```
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 files list file for package 'libstdc++-6-dev:amd64' contains empty filename
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

So how do I solve it?

Comment: You may need to regenerate the corrupted file by downloading the .deb and extracting the list of files from it - see for example [I get this error: dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting: files list file for package `fonts-tlwg-kinnari' contains empty filename](https://askubuntu.com/a/648754/178692)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to your root file system and go to

```
/var/lib/dpkg/info/
```

Cut all of the files there and create a new file called `info.bak` under

```
/var/lib/dpkg
```

Paste all of the files you cut earlier into `info.bak` and that solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

Does clearing the cached copy of that package help?

**apt-get clean** doesn’t always do a proper job, especially with half-installed packages, or packages marked with installation. My suspicion is that the deb file for libstdc++ got corrupted somehow in /var/cache/apt... no harm in deleting it or moving it out of there to apt will re-download a fresh copy. You could always also download it yourself, manually, check its hash to make sure download was ok, then use **dpkg -i xxx.deb** to install it the old-fashioned way.

Another thing to try is this method of cache cleanup:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/648736/i-get-this-error-dpkg-unrecoverable-fatal-error-aborting-files-list-file-for

Comment: Now a more serious problem, it booted into command interface instead of GUI

Comment: Unable to fetch, could open file (read-only)

Comment: More serious indeed! Are your disk(s) dying? Either that, or it could be filesystem issues. I suggest booting off USB and running a filesystem check on all partitions without mounting them. You can do that from gparted if you’d rather not deal with the shell.

Comment: Thats the first thing i did. No preblem at all.

Comment: And i dont know why it was marked read only... Trying to solve the issue

Comment: now both are solved, that was a fstab issue and the issue of could not install new packages solved by relocate the files under /var/lib/dpkg/info into /var/lib/dpkg/info.bak